# When do my items lose durability?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are weapons and armor damaged by anything other than death?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66663/are-weapons-and-armor-damaged-by-anything-other-than-death)

Okay, so each item has durability. Other than by death, what makes an item lose durability? I'm assuming attacking makes the weapon lose durability, but other than that:

- If I never get damage, does my armor lose durability?
- What affects the rate of durability loss? Why is my helmet currently at lower durability than my torso armor?
- What makes rings and amulets lose durability?
- If I use a lot of shift-clicking to attack at range, do I lose durability if I miss?

But I guess this all boils down to **when does an item lose durability, and at what rate does that happen?**